# WinForms TableLayoutPanel ComboBox not resizing properly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to use a TableLayoutPanel to align a few controls on a form next to their labels like so:

```
Label1      [combobox       ]
LongerLabel [longer combobox]
```

But when I run the project and grab the right hand side of the form and shrink the form, the combobox doesn't resize, it gets cut off... Now, I were to not use the TableLayoutPanel, but just anchor a combobox to a form's edges, it will resize properly. What am I doing wrong with the TableLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms.controls/2006-12/msg00209.html

So I set the first column with the label to autosize (I have the label fill docked in the cell and the text alignment set to middle left). Then dock fill the combobox in the second column. Then, set the second column's size type to 100%, NOT autosize. I don't know why it works, but it does.